# Notebooks used by Paul Erdős

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

Paul Erdős was known for living out of two half-full (or half-empty) suitcases; one had a few clothes and the other had mathematical papers. Some of these papers were probably referring to his notebooks; he was also known for carrying one notebook at all times.

As a notebook enthusiast, I was wondering if anyone knew whether Paul Erdős used a particular type of notebook: hard or soft cover, lined or unlined, small or legal paper size, etc. I tried searching for any details, like pictures of him holding a notebook, but to no avail. I hope this is the right place to ask.

Comment: Maybe this [picture](http://francis.naukas.com/files/2015/01/Dibujo20150120-Paul-Erdos-working-ams-org.jpg) helps?

Comment: @PichiWuana, it does, I can see way more loose leaf pages than expected; it's fascinating to see how other people work. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! ;)

Comment: Isn't the "History of Science and Mathematics" site more appropriate?

Comment: Notes by Erdős appear for example in this [paper](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~ronspubs/13_03_Egyptian.pdf) from R. Graham. Btw most of his papers are available [here](http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/Erdos.html).

Comment: @PrettyAntlers good luck with the search

Comment: @jim, my question is also off-topic on the [History of Science and Mathematics](http://meta.hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/1/are-questions-about-mathematicians-and-scientists-lives-on-topic) site because Paul Erdős' notebooks have no relation to his work, which is the focus there.

Comment: @PrettyAntlers Surprising, since he may have made comments on the margins, have given hints on the developments of various proof's *etc*.